# How do I get an IDbTransaction from an IDbContext?

Tags: entity-framework-core, dapper

An `IDbContext` has a `DatabaseFacade`, which has a `CurrentTransaction` property. But the `CurrentTransaction` is an `IDbContextTransaction`. I want to pass an `IDbTransaction` to Dapper.

How do I get an `IDbTransaction` instead of an `IDbContextTransaction`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update:** Actually EF Core provides extension method with the above signature out of the box. It's provided by the [`DbContextTransactionExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.dbcontexttransactionextensions) class. In order to use it, all you need is a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll` assembly and

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
```

**Obsolete:**
Currently (up to latest at this time EF Core 2.0) there is no official way to do that.

But you can use the following custom extension method to get it from `IDbContextTransaction`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using System.Data.Common;

public static class EFExtensions
{
    public static DbTransaction GetDbTransaction(this IDbContextTransaction source)
    {
        return (source as IInfrastructure<DbTransaction>).Instance;
    }
}
```

like

```
var dbTransaction = context.Database.CurrentTransaction.GetDbTransaction();
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. Now I can have an EF based repository which can switch to a Dapper query by passing it the connection and the current transaction.

Comment: Well, that's the theory. In practice, these things tend not to work. :)

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: When running a Dapper call within TransactionScope using a DbContext connection, it doesn't appear to rollback the transaction on an exception. It's as if it's ignoring the TransactionScope. Ultimately, I'm trying to start a DbContext transaction before some tests so that working db work is rolled back after a test.

Comment: I've tried creating a new connection for Dapper, but the db user login fails. Enlisting in ambient transactions isn't implemented on the current .net core release, so I may have to come back to this.

Comment: Indeed. Bummer.

Comment: (User login fails because EF appears to strip the password from the connection string copy it holds.)

Comment: How do you get the connection string - `context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString`?

Comment: Yes, that connection string doesn't work. A hard coded version works fine.

Comment: Anyhow, I'm giving up on this. I'm going to delete my data at the end of a test. You can't open multiple transactions with a DbContext. You can't use ambient transactions with .net core, at present. You can't use the same transaction with multiple connections. You can't use a single connection with a single transaction and roll it back after it's been committed. :)

Comment: Yeah. Meanwhile I found the EFC has a method like the one I wrote :)